# Prove that subset $U$ of $Y$ is open if $\exists V$ of $(X,d)$ such that $U=Y\cap V$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $Y \subset X$.

How do I start to prove that a subset $U \subseteq Y$ is open in the metric space $(Y,d|_{Y\times Y})$ iff an open subset $V$ of $(X,d)$ exists, such that $U=Y\cap V$?

What I've got so far: only that if $U=\emptyset$, the proof is trivial. I can't seem to get any further than that. Can anyone give me advice what to do next?

Comment: This is just the subspace topology, specializing to metric topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be open in $Y$. For each $p\in U$,then $\exists r_p>0$ such that $q\in Y,\ d(p,q)<r_p\implies q\in U$. Consider $$V_p=\{q\in X:d(p,q)<r_p\}$$ Then, $$U\subset G=\bigcup_{p\in U}V_p$$. Now, each $V_p$ is an open ball in $X$ and hence $G$ is an open subset of $X$. Now, $$U\subset G\cap Y$$ by construction and because of the choice of $r_p$'s we have $$V_p\cap Y\subset U\implies G\cap Y\subset U$$ Thus $U=G\cap Y$.

Now, let $U=G\cap Y$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$. Then, $\forall p\in U,\ \exists$ a neighborhood $V_p\subset G$. Then $V_p\cap Y\subset U\implies U$ is open relative to $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $U$ is open, then $\forall x\in U$, there exists a neighborhood $N^{\!Y}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)$ of $x$:
$$
N^{\!Y}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)\triangleq \{y\in Y|d(y,x)<\varepsilon\}
$$ 
But we also have:
$$
N^{\!Y}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)=N^{\!X}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)\cap Y
$$
where 
$$
N^{\!X}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)\triangleq \{y\in X|d(y,x)<\varepsilon\}
$$ 
Then it is obvious that $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}N^{\!Y}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)$ and $V=\bigcup_{x\in U}N^{\!X}_\varepsilon\!\!(x)$.